# Create Crosstab Using Percentile Counts In Python

Tags: python, dataframe, crosstab, percentile

I'm doing work involving stock market research and I wanted to create a crosstab to run a chi squared test on. I have stock market price change data as a data frame, and I wanted to create another crosstab based on counts by percentile of two of the columns. Ideally it'd look something like this:

|  | 0.25 | 0.5 | 0.75 | 1.0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.25 | 12 | 45 | 13 | 12 |
| 0.5 | 2 | 27 | 9 | 15 |
| 0.75 | 14 | 11 | 89 | 23 |
| 1.0 | 10 | 52 | 11 | 7 |

Where for example the (.75,.5) entry is the count of data points that lie between the 0.5 and 0.75 percentiles for the first variable and the 0.25 and 0.5 percentiles for the second variable. obviously those numbers probably aren't actually possible but you get the point.

All I can think of so far is just doing it by brute force where you get each percentile for each variable individually and then get the counts for each and add them in manually to a table. Is there any shorter way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Preparing a sample dataset

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,2), columns=['A', 'B'])
```

The percentiles can be computed using the qcut. The 4 is the number of percentiles you want to split your variable.

```
df['A_binned'] = pd.qcut(df['A'], 4)
df['B_binned'] = pd.qcut(df['B'], 4)
```

Counts the number of records in each percentile

```
dff = df.groupby(by=['A_binned', 'B_binned']).count().reset_index()
```

Finally you can pivot the dataframe

```
dff.pivot_table(index='A_binned', columns = 'B_binned', values='A')
```